# Add Facebook tab app to private page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

How do I let users add my [Facebook tab app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs) to their private profile pages?

I've managed to create an FB app, and I'm able to add it to a public page.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Scroll down to "Adding an App to a Page". Either let them use the JavaScript SDK or a simple URL Redirect.

It is not possible to use Apps on private/user profiles, you can only add them to Pages. That´s why they are called "Page Tabs".

Comment: The dialog that appears only allows me to add the app to a public page, not a profile.

Comment: oh, i thought you mean pages that are hidden. of course you can´t add apps to user profiles. i´ve added that to my answer.

Comment: But it has been possible earlier? I had an app (from ReverbNation) that worked in the same way, when it was connected I could add and remove different tabs. I tried removing it today, now I can't add it back.

Comment: some years ago, i think. and maybe you mean open graph, but that´s something completely different. anyway, apps can´t be added to user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add page tab apps to a private profile page any more.

It has been earlier, though, so if someone added an app they can still have it as a tab. Once removed, you can't get it back.